# C: uint16_t to bytes to add to sender payload and back again at receiver

Tags: c, byte

I keep on mucking about getting a uint16 added to the end of a payload and then at the receiver, getting it back again to a uint16 in c.

The uint16 is cmpId.
The sender does this:

```
        const UInt8* data = getArray(byteArray);
        data_length = getLenArray(byteArray)
        data_length = data_length + 2;
        UInt8 formatted_data[data_length];

        //serialize cmpid
        formatted_data[data_length-2] = cmpId & 0xff;
        formatted_data[data_length-1] = cmpId >> 8;
```

and the receiver does this:

```
        UInt8 len = (UInt8) ((smip_receive_t *) data)->payloadLen;
        UInt8 * payload = (UInt8 *) ((smip_receive_t *) data)->payload;

        UInt16 cmpid;
        cmpid = (payload[len-2] << 8) | payload[len-1];
```

But cmpId does not come through correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: Don't use homebrew names for fixed size types. Your title mentions a standard type, but your code uses unknown names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
formatted_data[data_length-2] = cmpId & 0xff;
formatted_data[data_length-1] = cmpId >> 8;
```

You should use:

```
cmpid = (payload[len-1] << 8) | payload[len-2];
```

Not:

```
cmpid = (payload[len-2] << 8) | payload[len-1];
```

Comment: @PaulR: Since OP does not use `memcpy`, Endianness of each side does not matter! The compiler on each side implements the bit-wise operations according to the HW architecture to which it is designated.

Comment: @PaulR: Just before you made that comment, I was about to write my own comment to the OP, telling him or her something like "good on you for not using `memcpy` here, which would make your code platform-dependent".

Comment: Nitpick: this code isn't portable to 8 and 16 bit systems. To ensure maximum portability, cast each operand to `uint16_t`.

Comment: @Lundin: I don't think that it's nitpicking. In particularly, if one of the communicating sides runs over an 8-bit CPU (in some embedded device, for example), or alternatively, if the compiler treats `payload[len-2] << 8` as an 8-bit value (though I'm not really sure what the standard says about this), which then "turns into 0". In any case, I think that this can cause an issue only over 8-bit platforms (not on 16-bit platforms). In addition, I think that one needs to cast only the shifted expression, i.e., `(uint16_t)payload[len-1] << 8`, and not both expressions.

Comment: The problem is a bit more severe than that. The compiler is not allowed to treat the left operand as anything but `int`. If `int` is 16 bits, the left operand is integer promoted to such a 16 bit _signed_ int. If it contained a value larger than 127, then data will get shifted into the sign bits and the code invokes undefined behavior. The compiler is only allowed to optimize the whole thing into a pure 8 bit operation if it can deduct that there are no side effects caused by integer promotion ("maybe the programmer _wanted_ undefined behavior").

Comment: It is correct that only the left expression needs the cast, but it is good practice to never let any form of implicit promotions occur in your code.

Comment: @Lundin: With regards to your previous comment - we still get a 16-bit value stored into a `UInt16` variable. Would could possibly cause undefined behavior here? Thanks.

Comment: There's the scenario of trap representations (which assumes some sort of semi-exotic system). Also, C does not specify what will happen if you shift data into the sign bits. Will there be a change of sign? Will the shifted-out data be ignored? We can't know. Worst of all, aggressively optimizing compilers can make assumptions such as the program does not need to work as intended if there is undefined behavior.